# PHP: I don't understand why this regex does not match this expression

Tags: php, regex

I would like to understand what this regex correspond to:

```
preg_match("/\/[A-z]{2}\/[^\/]*/", "expression_to_test")
```

I've tried with **/a2/** but it does not match. As I understand the regex, in this order we have: "/" which is a delimiter, "/" stands for backslash, [A-z]{2} stands for 2 letters, then another "/" then no "/" multiple times...

So, it's obviously not the good answer, if you find a matching pattern I would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Use one of the many [online regex splainers](https://regex101.com/).

Comment: Could you add more examples? so we know what you want to match and what you don't?

Comment: `A-z` includes more than `a-z` and `A-Z`.`/` is a forward slash. Is this used on a US website? Maybe looking for a state abbreviation in a URL?

Answer (score 1):

`a2` wont match `a-z` cause you have decimal number in there. Try this:

```
\/[A-Za-z0-9]{2}\/[^\/]*
```

https://regex101.com/r/iWSrPD/1

Comment: why would I be voted down for this answer. Please explain whats wrong with my answer?

Comment: Maybe because the OP isn't looking for a new regex rather `I would like to understand what this regex correspond to`. Not my vote so I can't say.

Comment: well the OP mentioned: `if you find a matching pattern I would be great.`

Comment: The real input is not provided though. e.g. is it `expression_to_test` or `/a2/` or something else. Neither of the two supplied strings would match and given the OP understands that (or should since he/she explained it) I think we're entering a rabbit hole.

Answer (score 1):

```
A-z a single character in the range between A (ASCII 65) and z (ASCII 122) (case sensitive)
```

`2` does not fall in it and so it fails.(as ascii for `2` is `50`)

`/Ab/` matches.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/woJSXd/1

See in table. Only from `65` to `122`

You need to use `[A-Za-z]` as `[A-z]` can match much more than intended.See table.

[image]